# How can I seed an enum by name from a Json file

Tags: c#, enums, entity-framework-core

I'm seeding data into my database on startup.

**Problem** - I want to seed the "YogaPose" by name, not number, as my YogaPose enum is really long (~150+) and trying to count the number is taking too long.

**Question** - Is this possible?

Here is what the code looks like to get the json data.

```
if (context.Poses.Any())
{
      var posesData =
         File.ReadAllText(path + @"/Data/SeedData/poses.json");

      var poses = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<List<Pose>>(posesData);

      foreach (var pose in poses)
      {
          context.Poses.Add(pose);
      }

      await context.SaveChangesAsync();
}
```

Here is a sample section from the json file, where you can see I'm using the YogaPose enum number. I want to use the name of the enum!

**Attempt 1** - I tried using "YogaPose": "YogaPose.Crane" with a failure

**Attempt 2** - I tried using "YogaPose": "Crane" with a failure

```html
{
        "YogaPose": 1,
        "Description": "A compact arm balance, Crane Pose/Crow Pose, called Bakasana in Sanskrit, encourages toning in the abs and the arms, strengthening in the core, and improves focus in the mind.",
        "Level": 2,
        "YogaPoseTypes": [{"YogaType": 1}],
        "Alias": "Crow",
        "Icon": "fa fa-users",
        "PreparatoryPoses": [{"YogaPose": 7},{"YogaPose": 44},{"YogaPose": 14},{"YogaPose": 122}],
        "FollowUpPoses": [{"YogaPose": 5},{"YogaPose": 7}]
    }
```

Here is the Pose entity

```
public class Pose : BaseEntity
{
    public YogaPose YogaPose { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public YogaLevel Level { get; set; }
    public ICollection<YogaPoseType> YogaPoseTypes { get; set; }
    public string Sanskrit { get; set; }
    public string Benefit { get; set; }
    public string Alias { get; set; }
    public string Icon { get; set; }
    public ICollection<PreparatoryPose> PreparatoryPoses { get; set; }
    public ICollection<FollowUpPose> FollowUpPoses { get; set; }
}
```

Here is a small section of the YogaPose enum

```
public enum YogaPose
{
    [Display(Name = "Crane")]
    Crane,
    [Display(Name = "Dolphin")]
    Dolphin
}
```

Comment: I think you are misusing enums. Enums are usually used for finite data sets like days of the week that do not change. Secondly if you have a pose entity, why do you need an enum at all. that aside, you likely just want another table, however its hard to tell at this stage

Comment: My enum "YogaPose" is a finite set that does not change...If you look at Pose, you'll see Pose keeps lots of data. But to what I'm asking, the construction of the entity and enum is irrelevant.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's possible but depends on a json converter you are using (Newstonsoft or System.Text.Json). Please, have a look to the article: [JsonConverter attributes](https://www.codeproject.com/Tips/5249190/JsonConverter-Attribute-in-ASP-NET-Core-3-0-Web-AP).

You also should prepare another json input file with strings instead of numbers in the field "YogaPose", for example:

```
{
    "YogaPose": "Crane",
    "Description": "A compact arm balance, Crane Pose/Crow Pose, called Bakasana in Sanskrit, encourages toning in the abs and the arms, strengthening in the core, and improves focus in the mind.",
    "Level": 2,
    "YogaPoseTypes": [{"YogaType": 1}],
    "Alias": "Crow",
    "Icon": "fa fa-users",
    "PreparatoryPoses": [{"YogaPose": 7},{"YogaPose": 44},{"YogaPose": 14},{"YogaPose": 122}],
    "FollowUpPoses": [{"YogaPose": 5},{"YogaPose": 7}]
}
```

Comment: I'm using System.Text.Json

Comment: Use `[JsonConverter(typeof(JsonStringEnumConverter))]` on your enum "YogaPose"